# How to ensure IMG Aligns in Center on col-xs, as well as making Divs 'float' in middle of space?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to understand 3 problems.

1) When minimizing to Col-XS, the picture is slightly off from centre - How do I fix this?

2) When the logo sits inside the Column, it forces the entire menu to widen due to the logo taking up space. This causes a huge amount of background colour (from the menu) to appear when not needed. Can anyone recommend a suitable fix for this (whether this be a design recommendation or a coding fix)?

3) If the above cannot be fixed, how do I make the 4x Menu items move from the top of the bar to the bottom? Would this be a job for Display: Relative or something like that? Or do the display tags not work within bootstrap (v3.3.5)?

Thanks in advance!

**Snippet**

```css
.logo {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
.header {
  background: #5A1FD3;
  border: 2px solid #46248B;
}
.header li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #5A1FD3;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
.header li:hover {
  transition: 1.5s;
  background: #46248B;
}
.header a:link {
  color: azure;
}
.header a:visited {
  color: azure;
}
.header a:active {
  color: azure;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- NAV MENU -->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="header col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="row text-center col-sm-3 col-xs-0">
        <img class="logo center-block" src="Pictures\Jamie Bohanna.png" alt="Logo">
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><a href="#header">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><a href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><a href="#Rates">Rates</a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12"><a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, for logical reasons, practical to use two rows. One for the logo and one for the list. And together they are the header:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-..."
                <img class="logo" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-..."
                <ul class="list-unstyled"><!-- .list-unstyled is a bootstrap class -->
                    <li>...</li>
                    <li>...</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- End of .header -->
</div>
```

`.container-fluid` has a `padding-left: 15px` and a `padding-right: 15px`, so that one can make

```
.header {
    margin: 0 -15px;
    ...
}
```

so that there will be no gap on the right and left side.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ce1e9gcu/)